# How do you get the string value of the first column in a two column item in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox which is populated through databinding to an ObservableCollection

```
<ListBox Height="198" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,45,0,0" Name="listBox_users" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" Name="left" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding real_name}" Name="right" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want to get the string value of just username for whatever item is selected. Generally in the past I've done this with a convoluted indexing system, but there must be a way to do it from listbox_users.Items or listbox_users.SelectedItem. I have no idea how to accomplish this in the context of databinding, I'm still very new to the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using data binding and setting the `ItemTemplate`, the `ListBox.SelectedItem` will return the `DataContext` of that item and not the templated element. I assume that the ItemsSource is a List of some type of view model. Here is an example where the ItemsSource is of type `ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>`

```
UserViewModel selectedUser = listBox_user.SelectedItem as UserViewModel;
string username = selectedUser.username;
```